# problem with a query which has OPTIONAL MATCH in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Consider the following schema, where orange nodes are of type `Friend` and pink node is of type `fbUser`.

[image]

The query that I am trying to write goes as follows:

> I'm trying to match all nodes which have a specific name in a specific range of time and
>   optionally related to each Friend node, every `tagged_together` relationship

So I wrote the following query:

```
MATCH x=(:fbUser {graph_information:['admin', 'facebook']})--(f:Friend) 
OPTIONAL MATCH y=(f)-[s:TAGGED_TOGETHER]-(d:Friend) 
WITH x,f,y,d,s 
WHERE  
    f.name=~ '(?i).*ruggeri.*' AND  
    f.timestamp>'2016-02-22' AND f.timestamp<'2020-02-22' AND
    d.timestamp>'2016-02-22' AND d.timestamp<'2020-02-22'
RETURN x,y
```

In this specific case,the output is correctly what I want, in fact I have this:

[image]

but if run the query with this line

```
WHERE  
        f.name=~ '(?i).*kirby.*' AND  
        f.timestamp>'2016-02-22' AND f.timestamp<'2020-02-22' AND
        d.timestamp>'2016-02-22' AND d.timestamp<'2020-02-22'
```

I expect this output

[image]

but I receive `(no changes, no records)`

Why?

What I've understand so far is that if an optional match doesn't have any results it returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ,

```
WHERE  
        f.name=~ '(?i).*kirby.*' AND  
        f.timestamp>'2016-02-22' AND f.timestamp<'2020-02-22' AND
        d.timestamp>'2016-02-22' AND d.timestamp<'2020-02-22'
```

When there are no tagged friends ,’d’ will be null and it cannot pass through these d.timestamp conditions

You can update your query like following to get the expected results ,

```
MATCH x=(:fbUser {graph_information:['admin', 'facebook']})--(f:Friend) 
OPTIONAL MATCH y=(f)-[s:TAGGED_TOGETHER]-(d:Friend) 
WITH x,f,y,d,s, case d when null then [] else [1] end as iterList 
WHERE  
    f.name=~ '(?i).*ruggeri.*' AND  
    f.timestamp>'2016-02-22' AND f.timestamp<'2020-02-22' AND ALL (x in iterList WHERE 
    d.timestamp>'2016-02-22' AND d.timestamp<'2020-02-22') 
RETURN x,y
```

I am creating an iteration list based on the d value . So , when it’s null , we won’t check the time stamps on d, since we are iterating through empty list . When d is not null, we will the time stamps on d .